# How to obtain $K$ in $K[1,2]$ in Maple?

Tags: math-software, maple

I would like to obtain the letter $K$ from $K[1,2]$ in Maple. I tried to use op(K[1, 2]). But I get $[1,2]$. Are there some function $f$ in Maple such that $f(K[1,2]) = K$? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try this: op(0, K[1, 2])

Comment: @twotwofive, thank you very much.